# Winget: works from limited user but not admin

Tags: powershell, winget

Windows machine has one administrative account and one limited user account. Windows's package manager, winget, works as expected from the limited user account that, IIRC, installed the app. It does not work--returns an error that 'winget' is unrecognized--when PowerShell is run as administrator from within that limited user account. How can this be? How can it be corrected?

Comment: run `gcm winget` in your limited user account (not admin). You'll see it's installed in `%localappdata%` of that user account. Install it for your admin account as well